# Remove outdent & indent from Redactor2 "lists" button

Tags: redactor

Redactor 2 introduced a single "lists" option for ordered and unordered lists but unfortunately this adds the outdent and indent options in as well.
Any way of removing outdent/indent again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to do this using a plugin which allows you to write CSS affecting the Craft CP.

Once: https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss is installed, click **Settings** > **Control Panel CSS** and add this to the "**Additional CSS**" field...

```
.redactor-dropdown-outdent, .redactor-dropdown-indent {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

This is what I end up with in Redactor...

[image]

Comment: No problem - glad to help